# What is use of build:babel and build:sass?

Tags: reactjs, sass, babeljs, node-sass

```
"build:babel": "babel --ignore src/vendor --source-maps -d build src",
"build:sass": "node-sass src/styles/index.scss --include-path node_modules -o build/styles --output-style compressed"
```

What meaning of this two lines?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you've taken these two lines from the `package.json` file of some kind of Node.js boilerplate project (presumably for React development). They define two npm scripts.

---

*I don't know how familiar you are with [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in general, so here's a quick explanation:*

When you are running the same command over and over again during the development of a Node.js project and want to make it easier for you and collaborators to run that command, you can create an npm script by adding the command to the `"scripts"` object in your `package.json` file and giving it a descriptive name. Using npm scripts also has the advantage that when running the script using [`npm run <name>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), npm will automatically find the local version of the package binaries (installed through the package's `dependencies` or `devDependencies`) that you are using in the script.

---

> `babel --ignore src/vendor --source-maps -d build src`

This script runs the [`babel-cli`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) and instructs it to [compile the entire `src` directory and output it to the `build` directory](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#compile-directories). *If you don't know already, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a tool to compile modern-day JavaScript to JavaScript that is also compatible with outdated browsers (or runtimes, etc.).*

> `node-sass src/styles/index.scss --include-path node_modules -o build/styles --output-style compressed`

This scripts runs the [`node-sass` CLI](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface) and instructs it to compile the `src/styles/index.scss` file, include the `node_modules` directory when looking for `@import`-ed files, compress the output and put the compiled CSS file into `build/css`. *If you don't know already, [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) is a superset of CSS that adds useful features like nesting.*