# How do I share components with external Sass stylesheets in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, babeljs, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to build a monorepo for my React projects as most of the code is shared between a few of my projects. I am using Yarn workspaces and Lerna for this.

I have managed to get a basic example working where the React component is shared between two projects. In this working example, however, the stylesheet is a plain CSS stylesheet and is correctly imported.
I am using Babel to transpile the React and ES6 code.

```
lerna exec --scope shared -- babel src -d dist --copy-files
```

where `shared` is my package containing shared components. Above command puts the transpiled JS and CSS files in the `dist` folder.

However, I have `.scss` files in my actual code base. Hence trying to replace external CSS file with external SCSS file in the example project. However, it doesn't work. The stylesheet isn't applied.

I think I understand why it must not be working. In CRA project whenever we use `.scss` file I think Webpack preprocesses these into `.css` files. In this is not happening hence the issue. Correct me if I am wrong.

I tried using Webpack instead of Babel. However, the issue that I faced was Webpack bundled all files into a single file which is something I don't want. I want that the individual component file should be transpiled and kept in the same folder structure under `dist`. Please see the folder structure below. `shared` is the package with shared components and `myapp` package uses the shared components.

```
workspace
--packages
  --shared
    --dist
      --components
          --button
            --Button.js
            --Button.scss
          --header
            --Header.js
            --Header.scss
    --src
       --components
          --button
            --Button.js
            --Button.scss
          --header
            --Header.js
            --Header.scss 

  ---myapp
```

My `webpack.config.js`

```
// Webpack uses this to work with directories
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: './src/index.js',

    // Path and filename of the result bundle.
    // Webpack will bundle all JavaScript into this file
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
        //filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|tiff)$/, use: 'file-loader' },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/, use: 'file-loader' }
        ]
    }
};
```

I am stuck at this point as I am not sure how I can import SCSS file in my React component which can be shared.

I'm not sure if there is a way to tell Webpack and Babel to transpile the React files and just put them in the `dist` folder without bundling them into a single file and also to preprocess the `.scss` files and use them in the transpiled files.

Comment: Babel is for transpiling JS, if you want to convert SCSS to CSS (without inlining and bundling it as Webpack's `sass-`, `css-` and `style-loader` do) you need e.g. [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49954734/3001761) seems to be asking about a setup similar to what I think you're looking for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Thanks for your help. So are you suggesting I should use node-sass to separately transform scss to css. I just realised if I do that I will have to change the ``import``` statement in the js file too while transpiling as currently I am importing ```scss``` file. I am wondering how ```webpack``` manages to do this. All I want is that the styles in the ```scss``` file should be applied to the corresponding component. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? I am also trying to achieve something similar.